# Update file description in google drive using javascript

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api, authorization

I am trying to update all my google drive images description. I have access to google drive and I am able to get results with

```
gapi.client.drive.files.list({
        'pageSize': 1000,
        'fields':'files,nextPageToken',
        'q':query,
        'orderBy':'name',
        'access_token':accesToken
    });
```

After that I want to update all files description but I got the result that I need to login. I am using OAuth 2.0 Playground with permission to all my drive.

```
gapi.client.drive.files.update({
        'fileId': fileid,
        'access_token':accesToken,
        'resource': body
    });
```

Any idea how to login or what I am not doing right?

Answer (score 0):

Try to double check if you follow properly the steps [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/about-auth) to Authorize your requests with OAuth, also make sure that you use the correct scope in your application. Here is the [link](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/about-auth#what_scope_or_scopes_does_my_app_need) that will explain you the meaning and purpose of each scope.

Now to update your file, this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/update) can help you with that. The [v2 version](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/update) of this documentation has an example of Javascript code that updates the file.

```
/**
 * Update an existing file's metadata and content.
 *
 * @param {String} fileId ID of the file to update.
 * @param {Object} fileMetadata existing Drive file's metadata.
 * @param {File} fileData File object to read data from.
 * @param {Function} callback Callback function to call when the request is complete.
 */
function updateFile(fileId, fileMetadata, fileData, callback) {
  const boundary = '-------314159265358979323846';
  const delimiter = "\r\n--" + boundary + "\r\n";
  const close_delim = "\r\n--" + boundary + "--";

  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.readAsBinaryString(fileData);
  reader.onload = function(e) {
    var contentType = fileData.type || 'application/octet-stream';
    // Updating the metadata is optional and you can instead use the value from drive.files.get.
    var base64Data = btoa(reader.result);
    var multipartRequestBody =
        delimiter +
        'Content-Type: application/json\r\n\r\n' +
        JSON.stringify(fileMetadata) +
        delimiter +
        'Content-Type: ' + contentType + '\r\n' +
        'Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n' +
        '\r\n' +
        base64Data +
        close_delim;

    var request = gapi.client.request({
        'path': '/upload/drive/v2/files/' + fileId,
        'method': 'PUT',
        'params': {'uploadType': 'multipart', 'alt': 'json'},
        'headers': {
          'Content-Type': 'multipart/mixed; boundary="' + boundary + '"'
        },
        'body': multipartRequestBody});
    if (!callback) {
      callback = function(file) {
        console.log(file)
      };
    }
    request.execute(callback);
  }
}
```

For the sample javascript code in v3, check this [link](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/quickstart/js).

Comment: please update your last link, it links to the quickstart guide for javascript of the googles drive api and has nothing explaining how to use the update function.